# Call a function from an if-statement inside a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement, ecmascript-6

I have a function with an if-statement that in turn should call an outside function whether or not something is true. The result I get is 'undefined'. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Function 1:

```
function printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
    let summa = [];

    for (i = rangeStart; i <= rangeStop; i++) {
        summa.push(i);
    }
    let result2 = summa.join();
    return result2;
}
```

Function 2:

```
function printRangeReversed(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
    let summa = [];

    for (i = rangeStart; i >= rangeStop; i--) {
        summa.push(i);
    }
    let result3 = summa.join();
    return result3;
}
```

Function 3:

```
function printAnyRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {

    if (rangeStart < rangeStop) {
        printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop);
    } else {
        printRangeReversed(rangeStart, rangeStop);
    }
    return;
}
```

Calling the function: `printAnyRange(21, 45);`

As I said it all looks logical to me but I guess it isn't since I get the 'undefined'.

Expected result should be: `"21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45"`

Regards.

Comment: Your `return` statement is not followed by an expression, so the function returns `undefined`. Your other functions return values, but when your main function calls them it does not save the values returned.

Comment: a) you don't return anything from `printAnyRange` and b) you dont' even "capture" the values returned from the other functions ... so, no surprise you get undefined at all

Comment: "*I have a function with an if-statement that in turn should call an outside function whether or not something is true. The result I get is 'undefined'.*" All of this is correct and as expected. What is your question?

Comment: @melpomene Sorry, added the expected result now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning anything. Capture the result of the functions and return that variable.

```js
function printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
    let summa = [];

    for (i = rangeStart; i <= rangeStop; i++) {
        summa.push(i);
    }
    let result2 = summa.join();
    return result2;
}

function printRangeReversed(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
    let summa = [];

    for (i = rangeStart; i >= rangeStop; i--) {
        summa.push(i);
    }
    let result3 = summa.join();
    return result3;
}

function printAnyRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
    let result = null;

    if (rangeStart < rangeStop) result = printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop);
    else result = printRangeReversed(rangeStart, rangeStop);
        
    return result;
}

console.log(printAnyRange(1,5));
console.log(printAnyRange(5,1));
```

Answer (score 2):

The value that is getting returned from `function 1` and `function 2` is not being using or stored by `function 3`. Try following code:

```
function printAnyRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {

    if (rangeStart < rangeStop) {
        return printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop);
    } else {
        return printRangeReversed(rangeStart, rangeStop);
    }
}
console.log(printAnyRange(10, 15));
```

this should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something with the returned values, like log them:

```
function printAnyRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {

    if (rangeStart < rangeStop) {
        console.log(printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop));
    } else {
        console.log(printRangeReversed(rangeStart, rangeStop));
    }
    return;
}
```

Or return them from the main function:

```
function printAnyRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {

    if (rangeStart < rangeStop) {
        result = printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop);
    } else {
        result = printRangeReversed(rangeStart, rangeStop);
    }
    return result;
}
```